# Confusing results of standard deviation computing in groupby object with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say the dataframe has the columns `name`,`category`, `rank`, where `name` is the name of an individual, `category` is a categorical variable , `rank` the rank of the individual in one row.

First I wanted the mean for each `name` and `category` as:

```
X = df.groupby(['name','category'])['rank'].agg('mean')
#out:
+---------+-------------------+------+
|  name   | category          |      |
+---------+-------------------+------+
| 1260229 |                 9 | 11.0 |
|         |                18 | 9.50 |
| 1126191 |                 5 | 4.00 |
|         |                17 | 3.00 |
|         |                23 | 4.00 |
| 1065670 |                33 | 3.00 |
|         |                39 | 5.00 |
|         |                41 | 8.00 |
+---------+-------------------+------+
```

Now the standard deviation,

```
X.reset_index().groupby('name')['rank'].agg(np.std)
#out:
+---------+------+
|  name   |      |
+---------+------+
| 1260229 | 1.06 |
| 1126191 | 0.58 |
| 1065670 | 2.51 |
+---------+------+
#Note here that "rank" is actually the mean of rank by category. I just didn't change the name
#of the column for the new dataframe issued from X.reset_index()
```

The problem is when I compute (for the individual `1260229`) as `np.std([11,9.50])` it returns `0.75` and not `1.06`, same issue for other individuals.

I don't get where is the wrong manipulation to make these wrong results.

---

Pandas version: 0.23.4
Python version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas is default `ddof=1` in [`DataFrame.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), in numpy [`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) is `0`.

You can use instead second groupby only `std` with `level=0` parameter for simplify solution:

```
s = X.std(level=0)
print (s)
name
1260229    1.060660
1126191    0.577350
1065670    2.516611
Name: rank, dtype: float64

s = X.std(level=0, ddof=1)
print (s)
name
1260229    1.060660
1126191    0.577350
1065670    2.516611
Name: rank, dtype: float64
```

And also `ddof=0`:

```
s = X.std(level=0, ddof=0)
print (s)
name
1260229    0.750000
1126191    0.471405
1065670    2.054805
Name: rank, dtype: float64
```

If want use `groupby` also it is possible:

```
s = X.groupby(level=0, sort=False).std(ddof=0)
print (s)
name
1260229    0.750000
1126191    0.471405
1065670    2.054805
Name: rank, dtype: float64
```